# cin.ignore() is not working in program

Tags: c++

My program is suppose to output First Middle Last name and ignore the , that is in the input.  But in my program the comma is still in my output so obviously I am missing something.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
char chr;
int main()
{
string last, first, middle;
cout<< "Enter in this format your Last name comma First name Middle name."<<endl;   //Input full name in required format
cin>>last;                                                                          //receiving the input Last name 
cin>>first;                                                                         //receiving the input First name
cin>>middle;                                                                        //receiving the input Middle name
cout<<first<<" "<<middle<< " " <<last;                                              //Displaying the inputed information in the format First Middle Last name
cin.ignore(',');                                                                    //ignoring the , that is not neccesary for the new format
cin>>chr;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: you accept the names from cin before you ignore the comma?

Comment: also i dont think you want cin.ignore

Comment: Can you explain what you are expecting this to do? Looks like your `cin.ignore(',')` is in the wrong place [and with the wrong arguments].

Comment: Calling `cin.ignore` after you get the strings in which you wanted to ignore `','` is probably the issue. You'll want to call it before you call `cin.operator>>` to get the last, first, and middle so that before you extract input `cin` already is set to filter out `','`.

Answer (score 2):

The `ignore` function acts on the current input stream (e.g. `cin`), and it discards as many characters as indicated in the first argument, until it finds the delimiter given as the second argument (default as `EOF`).

So, the way you have it, `cin.ignore(',');` will ignore 44 characters until EOF, after you have printed the inputs given. This is almost certainly NOT what you wanted to do.

If you want to skip past a comma, then you will want to call `cin.ignore(100, ',');` between the input of the last name and the input of first name. That will skip to the next comma in the input (up to 100 characters).

Comment: I have tried changing cin.ignore(','); to cin.ignore(100,','); and putting it between the cinlast and first I have also put it in several other places and it just causes my output to not appear.  My program is supposed to have the user input their name with the format Last, first middle then output first middle last no comma.

Comment: I messaged my instructor for assistance with my cin.ignore and this is what she messaged me back.       The problem is that when you read in last – it includes the comma.  So your cin.ignore needs 2 arguments, 100, \n.  In this case, you don’t need the cin.ignore.  Just read in first and then middle.  Then use string functions to “find” the comma and create a substring from last starting at position 0 to the place before the comma.  The problem is I have no idea what she is talking about.  I know how to put in a find function but                       the second part I am not getting.